# Installing MDM on Windows: can my user name contain spaces?

Tags: workload-scheduler

I have installed an IWS master domain manager on Windows using Installation Manager. The installation completes successfully.
However, when I try to use the product, I always receive a message to the effect that I am not not authorized.
I have checked the security file and my user name is present, but only the first half of the user name is listed: say, I have used user "John Doe" and in the security file, only "John" is present.

Answer (score 0):

when installing IWS on Windows systems, spaces are not supported in usernames. Try using JohnDoe instead, and that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run Installation Manager to install IWS when you are logged on Windows with a user containing spaces.
Use an administrative Windows user that doesn't contains spaces.